# Do upgraded weapons persist if I sell / drop the item?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

In Deus Ex: Human Revolution, if I upgrade a weapon using one of the upgrade items, such as a suppressor or an ammo-capacity upgrade, etc., then I either sell the weapon, or drop it.  Do all weapons of the same type subsequently have the upgrade?

For possible bonus points: Do all weapon drops of the same type from enemies have the same attributes?

Comment: I can't answer authoritatively, but from what I recall - dropped weapons will retain their upgrades, but the upgrades are specific to that instance of the weapon (ie, shop weapons or later weapons will be "stock" instead of upgraded)

Comment: that's what I recall as well

Comment: I concur. But you shouldn't need any weapon other than the stun gun to win the game - any other pacifists around here?

Comment: yeah I have pacifist - I used the tranquilliser rifle instead of the stun gun though

Comment: I'm a pacifist too tbh.  Haven't killed anyone yet (except some boss guy who didn't seem to be stunnable - that was annoying), but I keep upgrading the combat rifle just in case ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - the weapons and items in Deus Ex: Human Revolution are unique - if you upgrade a weapon and then subsequently drop your weapon and find another of the same type, it will be a standard instance of the weapon with no upgrades.

If you go back to where you dropped your weapon and pick it back up, the weapon that you pick up will have the same upgrades as when you dropped it.

In the event that you sell a weapon, buying it back will purchase a standard instance of the weapon with no upgrades.